# ¿Cómo hacer que un número aparezca con sus dígitos separados por espacios?

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo que hacer un programa que lea un número entero de cualquier longitud e imprima en pantalla este mismo número pero con sus dígitos separados por dos espacios. Este es el programa que tengo hecho pero no sé en qué falla:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Spanish");
    long long numero, numero2;
    int contador;

    cout << "Introduzca un número: ";
    cin >> numero >> numero2;

    while(numero2>10){

        contador=0;

        while(numero2>10){
            numero2/=10;
            contador++;
        }
        cout << numero2 << "\t";

        for(contador=contador; contador==0; contador--){

            numero2=numero/(contador*10)-numero2*(10*contador);
        }

        numero=numero2;

    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Cómo hacer que un número aparezca con sus dígitos separados por espacios?

Extrae dígito a dígito e imprimelo. Dado que tratamos con números en base 10 será tan fácil como obtener el residuo de la división entre 10. El problema es que esto mostraría el número en orden inverso, pero es fácil de solucionar si guardamos los dígitos en una cadena de caracteres en orden inverso:

```
std::string con_espacios(int numero)
{
    std::string result{};
    while (numero)
    {
        result.insert(0, 1, '0' + (numero % 10));
        result.insert(0, 1, '\t');
        numero /= 10;
    }

    return result;
}
```

La función `con_espacios` se puede usar así:

```
std::cout << con_espacios(0x7fffffff) << '\n';
std::cout << con_espacios(666) << '\n';
std::cout << con_espacios(7'654'321) << '\n';
```

Y muestra lo siguiente:

> ```
>   2   1   4   7   4   8   3   6   4   7
>   6   6   6
>   7   6   5   4   3   2   1
> ```

Si quieres evitar la tabulación de más, no la insertes si el número es menor que 10.

También puedes usar la versión recursiva:

```
std::string con_espacios(int numero)
{
    const char digito = '0' + (numero % 10);
    const std::string result({digito, '\t'});

    if (numero < 10)
        return result;

    return con_espacios(numero / 10).append(result);
}
```

El *truco* de la versión recursiva es que al deshacer la recursión se concatena (`std::basic_string::apend`) de final (dígito más significativo) a principio (dígito menos significativo).

Ten en cuenta que esta versión de la función añade la tabulación de más al final en lugar de al principio. Por último, puedes pasar el número a cadena y copiarlo en una cadena con espacios poniendo los dígitos en las posiciones impares:

```
std::string con_espacios(int numero)
{
    std::string texto = std::to_string(numero);
    std::string result(texto.size() * 2, ' ');

    int indice = 0;

    for (const auto &digito : texto)
    {
        result[indice] = digito;
        indice += 2;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4):

Creo que es complicársela en vano, no los trates como números si no vas a realizar otra operación que no sea imprimirlos en pantalla. En cambio, te conviene tratarlos como strings. Acá te dejo un simple ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string numero;
    int contador;

    cout << "Introduzca un numero, 0 para terminar\n";
    cin >> numero;

    while(numero != "0"){
        for (int i = 0; i < numero.length(); i++)
            cout << numero[i] << " ";
        cout << endl;

        cout << "Introduzca un número, 0 para terminar\n";
        cin >> numero;
    }
}
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Saludos!

Comment: Wow muchas gracias!